# MultiThreading in billing system

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, cluster-computing

I have to develop a telecom billing system in Java, so the system must calculate more than 100 000 bills per day.
Should i use multithreading in one PC, ora clustering to distribute the load on two or three servers?
I add that it is just for a personal purpose( university project).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: That's ~ 1 bill per second, which is not a lot: you probably don't even need multithreading. Unless the 100,000 all need to be processed within a few seconds.

Comment: 100000 bills per day can vary from about 1 bill per second (if they're distributed uniformly) as so one PC is enough and to spare, up to 100000 bills per second (if there's one sharp casp) and you have to use a powerful claster. What's the statictics? What's one PC performance? These questions you should answer

Comment: in fact, the system define the list of client who should be charged, then it calculate for each one his bill, then generate a PDF. i supposed that one bill require 1 seconde so for 100 000 bills it takes 27 hours. Unfortunatly i dont have a prototype.

Answer (score 1):

Since it is for a personal purpose (University Project), I would suggest you to got for multithreading in one PC. This will help you to understand Multithreading concept also very well.